# How to create migrations and models from existing database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, database-migration, laravel-artisan

Is it possible to create migrations and models form existing database in Laravel 5? 
Should I do that by artisan command or maybe use special library?

How about your experience in that topic? 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator for this. But be aware that it might not create 100% usable migrations that reflect in 100% real database structure, so you should manually review migrations to make sure everything is it should be.

Comment: Thanks, does it also put basic records to database. I mean basic seeding is made?

Comment: I used it quite a long time ago. As far as I remember it doesn't support seeding but maybe it has been changed